# How do you achieve this "scrolling and changing multiple background picture" effect?

Tags: html

I was looking at this HTML5 website, [http://www.danhigbie.com](http://www.danhigbie.com/), and found the "background image's scrolling" fascinating. I looked through its Javascript but found no code changing the background image.

Comment: Here's another (and better, I think) example. http://www.nikebetterworld.com/index

Comment: excellent site phoffer... damn i need to know how to do that background image effect.. looks damn cool

Answer (score 1):

Save the webpage to disk and play around with the files `better.js` and `better.cs`. The background scrolling is being done in the `better.js` file by changing the css classes (which are defined in `better.css`)

Comment: i still don't get it. From better.js, only 'better' class and 'scrolled' class are added when a certain scroll height is reached. No other class affects the background change. How do the first bg(brown wall) transits to the second bg(blue sky) from the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

I am using some jQuery to change the background positioning of multiplebgs based on the scroll position. Each background image element is positioned from the top with a percentage, this may be a bit hard to follow since there are so many background images per section. I take each background elements vertical position value and modify it based on the current scroll bar position. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the effect is done simply by declaring the background position of different "section" as fixed. Found a excellent article that explains how that effect work:

[Icon that changes color when scrolling](http://www.wickham43.net/iconcolorchange.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript library that does this for you and seems to work really well:
http://stolksdorf.github.com/Parallaxjs/